# How to accept socket with timeout

Tags: c, linux, windows

Is there is a timeout crossplatform soulution to accept client using `accept` function without setting socket to non-blocking?

I know that i should use `select` function to it, but what i'm doing wrong?

```
SOCKET NativesAcceptClient(SOCKET s, int timeout)
{
   int iResult;
   struct timeval tv;
   fd_set rfds;
   FD_ZERO(&rfds);
   FD_SET(s, &rfds);

   tv.tv_sec = (long)timeout;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   iResult = select(s, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
   if(iResult > 0)
   {
      return accept(s, NULL, NULL);
   }
   else
   {
     //always here, even if i connect from another application
   }
   return 0;
}
```

How to fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: @ryanbwork no, timeout is 10

Comment: is it immediately popping out of select or is it waiting 10s before popping out (if you don't connect to it)?  it looks ok (aside from the s+1 mentioned for non-Windows platforms), something else is amiss...

Comment: @Boris, did you ever solve this problem?  If so, could you select an answer or write one of your own?

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of the `select` call should be equal to the the highest number file descriptor in your fd_set set plus 1 (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)). Try changing the first argument to `s+1`; you will need to add some logic when your have more than one socket in your set.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm testing now on Windows, as i know first parameter is ignored on windows

Comment: Can you ensure that your incoming connection is taking place within your 10 second window?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of select() is an int that is at least 1 *greater* than the highest value of the file descriptors in any of the bitsets.  In this case

```
iResult = select(s + 1, &rfds, (fd_set *) 0, (fd_set *) 0, &tv);
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

`select()` returns >0 if a socket is signaled, 0 on timeout, and -1 on error.  What value is `select()` actually returning to you?  You are only checking for >0 and <=0, which means you are not differentiating between -1 and 0.  If it is returning 0 then no client is connecting to your socket, but if it is returning -1 then your socket is likely not valid to begin with.