# Closing a server socket in C linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a server program which looks like this

```
{
    socket();
    bind();
    listen();

    while(1)
    {
        accept();
        recv();
        send();
        close();
    }

    close();
}
```

Let's say the server is running, listening at the specified port. How can I close it by pressing a keypad? I mean a proper closure, not by Ctrl+C.

Comment: As @guido said you can [poll the socket for connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045064/how-to-accept-socket-with-timeout).

Answer (score 1):

When you `close()` a socket that is blocking in `accept()`, then the `accept()` call will return immediately with -1.

If your program is single threaded like you show, then you can't do the above. You would need to introduce at least one additional thread to actually do the `close()`.

Comment: Either this or use epoll/select to multiplex stdin and the listener socket.

Comment: You could let the libc/OS implictily introduce the "addtional thread" by signaling the program.

Comment: @Guido, make your answer

Comment: I believe this is an incorrect answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365282/c-linux-accept-blocking-after-socket-closed

Answer (score 0):

1. Have the program install a signal handler (for `SIGUSR1` for example) doing nothing.
2. Use `setsockopt()` to unset the option `SA_RESTART` for the sockets in use.
3. Make the code issuing socket related system calls aware that they might return with `-1` and `errno` set to `EINTR`.
4. Run the    program.
5. Send it a signal for which the program has a handler    installed (in 1.) from the outside (by for example using the `kill <pid> -USR1` command).
6. Detect the reception of a signal (see 3.) and react, for example by `close()`ing the socket in question.